# Threads and Synchronization general approach

Tags: java, multithreading, server, protocols

I'm coding a multithreading server. I got the server itself, many Client objects (each for every connection, in the Thread-Per-Client design) and one single Protocol instance. The Protocol object decides what do with every message the Client send.

I got ONE Protocol object, that many Client object can access, at the same time. The Protocol object got no variables of its own, but it access other objects.

My question is: Can it cause problem, that many clients are accessing the same object at the same time (giving the object got no variables)

Comment: Hard to say without some code. Whether it has variables or not is not relevant, it's important which variables it actually accesses. The general answer is yes, it can.

Comment: On top of that, there are so many things that can go wrong in a multithreaded application so you need to prepare real hard. Read Java Concurrency in Practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object has no data, only methods, it's okay to access it in a multithreaded way.  However, in your case, your Protocol object accesses other objects, so while your threads may not be sharing data in the Protocol object itself, they will be sharing those other objects and the data in them.  Without proper synchronization, that can cause problems.